# Trying to compile c code with cpp .so lib, with extern "C" { ... } segment

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I need to compile c code with `-lfoo` cpp lib.

foo.cpp looks like:

```
#include "foo.hpp"

extern "C" {
/* some come for my class, that describes in  foo.hpp*/
}
```

foo.hpp :

```
class Bar{
public:
/* public fields  */
/* public methods */
}
```

So can i do that?

Comment: You cannot use C++ classes from C code if that is what you are asking. The common workaround is to provide a set of C++ functions that call the methods for you.

Comment: Your C code needs to use a valid C header with a C interface (and you need to define such an interface). `extern "C"` only affects naming, it does not automagically make your C++ code usable from C.

Comment: @Botje A set of C functions, I guess.

Comment: C++ can use C routines.  C routines cannot use C++ objects (not directly; a C compatible interface can be made, but that's not automatic you have to make it yourself).

Comment: @evg C++ functions with an `extern "C"` tag to make them callable from C without mangling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use your lib from C code, the lib cannot export classes.

You can only have function. you can hide classes behind opaque pointers passed out.

In the library, use C++ as you wish, as long as all interface functions are plain-C and do not use classes or pointers-to-classes.

For example, this header has a class 'A' with a function 'add' , and also provides 3 functions that can be used to use the functionality from a C caller.

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus

// the class-definition is hidden when included from C.
class A
{
  public:
    A(int val);

    int add(int b) const;
  private:
    int m_val;
};

extern "C"
{
#endif

// exported functions. Exported in C compatible way.

// create an 'A', pass out as void*
void *create(int val);

// destroy the 'A' object. Call destroy inside.
void destroy(void *hdl);

// use the exported function. hdl is the return value from 'create()'.
int add_A(void *hdl,int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Inside, the function wrap the class and hide it.

```
void *create(int val)
{
    return new A(val);
}

void destroy(void *hdl)
{
    delete ((A*)hdl);
}

int add_A(void *hdl,int b)
{
    return ((A*)hdl)->add(b);
}

A::A(int val)
{
 ////........... implementation of A class follows here.
```